# Преобразовать описание вхождение папок - Java SE

Tags: java, файлы

В текстовом документе в каждой строчке указан путь папок:

```
abc < a < qw
q < e < wsx
abc < qa < z
qw < lnz < ert
qa < z < we < m
we < d
```

Нужно получить текстовый документ с полными каталогами папок от самого корня:

```
abc < a < qw < lnz < ert
q < e < wsx
abc < qa < z < we < m
abc < qa < z < we < d
```

Comment: Как реализовать подобный алгоритм?

Comment: имена папок уникальны или может быть "a < b < c, a < c < b"?

Comment: Уникальны, все верно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения:

```
String text;
File file = new File("Имя  вашего файла");

try(FileInputStream stream =
                    new FileInputStream(file)) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int i;

    while ((i = stream.read()) != -1)
        builder.append((char) i);

        text = builder.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        text = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        text = null;
    }

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = 
                           new StringTokenizer(text, "\n");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream=
                    Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(token))){

            System.out.println("Каталог: "+token);

            for (Path path : dirStream) {

                BasicFileAttributes attributes =
                        Files.readAttributes(
                                path, BasicFileAttributes.class);

                if(attributes.isDirectory())
                    System.out.print("<DIR> ");
                else
                    System.out.print("      ");

                System.out.println(path.getName(1));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Каталог не найден");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можете мне объяснить как это добро работает, как мне ему подавать строки  с моими каталогами?

Comment: Вы можете извлекать строки поочередно в цикле и сразу же их отдавать в Path.get (). Сами же строки можно получить если прочитать файл в строку и далее разделить строку, с помощью new StringTokenizer("строка", "\n") получить отдельную часть.

Comment: Можете переписать этот алгоритм для моего случая?

Comment: Теперь вам нужно позаботиться чтоб имена директории были разделены \n, были закрытыми и т.д.